# What are "first principles"

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am watching a discrete math video where the professor says that using the Pigeonhole principle is easier than using the first principles.  What exactly are the first principles and what in general does this statement mean?

Comment: could mean axioms? which would truly be the first principles. check out Peano Arthimatic or axiomatic set theory. and try proving things just using those. this is the equivantly of proving without any theorems like the pigeon hole principle

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_principle "*a basic, foundational, self-evident proposition or assumption that cannot be deduced from any other proposition or assumption.*"  In practice, it is "from the ground up" assuming no prior mathematical background.

Comment: also the pigeon hole principle isn't always true check out https://blogs.chapman.edu/press-room/2016/01/19/the-quantum-pigeonhole-principle-can-three-pigeons-be-in-two-pigeonholes-with-no-two-pigeons-in-the-same-hole/ it all depends on axioms

Comment: @Jmoravitz Thanks for the link, I started to wonder what was the difference to an axiom, but it turned out to mean the same in philosophic lingo.

Comment: @shaihorowitz Hah, quantumn pigeons.

Comment: I had the pure math version of it but lost it